# Query regarding password hashing. Cannot log in

Tags: c#, hash, authentication, registration

i am trying to encrypt a password and be able to log in with it. here is my hash code inside my businesslayer folder under shopping cart class.

```
 public static string CreateSHAHash(string Phrase)
    {
        SHA512Managed HashTool = new SHA512Managed();
        Byte[] PhraseAsByte = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(string.Concat(Phrase));
        Byte[] EncryptedBytes = HashTool.ComputeHash(PhraseAsByte);
        HashTool.Clear();
        return Convert.ToBase64String(EncryptedBytes);
    }
```

and here is my registration code where i included the hash with the password. i am successful in registering an account and having an encrypted password in my database with this:

```
protected void btn_Registration_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RegistrationConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
            conn.Open();
            string insertQuery = "insert into UserData(Username,Firstname,Lastname,Email,Password,CustomerType,DeliveryAddress,Zip,ContactNumber)values(@Username,@Firstname,@Lastname,@Email,@Password,@CustomerType,@DeliveryAddress,@Zip,@ContactNumber)";
            SqlCommand scm = new SqlCommand(insertQuery, conn);
            scm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", txtUser.Text);
            scm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Firstname", txtFN.Text);
            scm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Lastname", txtLN.Text);
            scm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", txtEmail.Text);
            scm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", BusinessLayer.ShoppingCart.CreateSHAHash(txtPW.Text));
            scm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerType", RadioButtonList1.SelectedItem.ToString());
            scm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DeliveryAddress", txtAddress.Text);
            scm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Zip", txtZip.Text);
            scm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ContactNumber", txtContact.Text);

            scm.ExecuteNonQuery();
            Session["Contact"]= txtContact.Text;
            Session["Email"] = txtEmail.Text;
            Session["DeliveryAddress"] = txtAddress.Text;
            label_register_success.Text = ("Registration Successful!");
            //Response.Redirect("Home.aspx");
            conn.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write("Error:" + ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

However, when i try to log in with the password that i have registered, its not letting me in. here is the code:

```
protected void btn_Login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source = 'PAULO'; Initial Catalog=ShoppingCartDB;Integrated Security =True");
        conn.Open();
        string checkuser = "select count(*) from UserData where Username = '" + txtUser.Text + "'";
        SqlCommand scm = new SqlCommand(checkuser, conn);
        int temp = Convert.ToInt32(scm.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
        conn.Close();
        if (temp == 1)
        {
            conn.Open();
            string checkPassword = "select Password from UserData where Username ='" + txtUser.Text + "'";
            SqlCommand passCom = new SqlCommand(checkPassword, conn);
            string password = passCom.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
            if (password == BusinessLayer.ShoppingCart.CreateSHAHash(txtPassword.Text))
            {
                Session["New"] = txtUser.Text;
                Response.Write("<script>alert('Logged In')</script>");
                Response.Redirect("OrderNow.aspx");
            }
            else
            {
                lblcrederror.Text = ("Credentials dont match");
            }

        }
        else
        {
            lblcrederror.Text = ("Credentials dont match");
        }
    }
```

what am i missing here? thank you

Comment: You probably want to read this first. 

http://codahale.com/how-to-safely-store-a-password/ and then use something like https://bcrypt.codeplex.com

Comment: There's nothing wrong with password hash function. I suspect the ``Password`` field in the table is not long enough.

Comment: @ub3rst4r i noticed that my sql connection are different from the registration and log in. so i changed it. also, password column is in nvarchar(MAX). still cannot log in :(